# Unhandled Exception Error visual studio 2010 C++ (open gl)

Tags: c++, opengl, unhandled-exception

Im trying to code a 3D model that I am reading in verts from a .obj It was all working with a standard teapot model, so I decided to create a spaceship for the actual assignment. I then changed it with the teapot file and then changed the arrays to be big enough for the vert and vertex normal's etc to fit before before trying to run the program to which i got a unhandled error access violation error. Below is all of the code that the program uses glut library which I have to use..

As a side note I am trying to make it so my camera moves around the spaceship as its origin.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include "glut.h"
#include <istream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

struct point3D
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct camera
{
    point3D pos;
    point3D lookAt;
    point3D up;

};

camera cam = {0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};


point3D v[162] = {};
point3D vn[74] = {};
point3D vt[150] = {};
point3D f[110][3] = {};

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.7, 0.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 500);

}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity(); // reset the matrix
    gluLookAt(cam.pos.x, cam.pos.y, cam.pos.z,
              cam.lookAt.x, cam.lookAt.y, cam.lookAt.z,
              cam.up.x, cam.up.y, cam.up.z);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -15.0f);


    for(int i = 0; i < 110; i++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        int one = f[i][0].x;
        int two = f[i][1].x;
        int three = f[i][2].x;

        glVertex3fv(&(v[one].x));
        glVertex3fv(&(v[two].x));
        glVertex3fv(&(v[three].x));
        glEnd();
    }


    glFlush();
}


void specialKeyboard(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            cam.pos.x+=0.2;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            cam.pos.x-=0.2;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:
            cam.pos.y+=0.2;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            cam.pos.y-=0.2;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
            cam.pos.z+=0.2;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
            cam.pos.z-=0.2;
            break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();

}

void normalKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key)
    {

        case 'w' :
            cam.lookAt.y+=0.5;
            break;
        case 'a' :
            cam.lookAt.y-=0.5;
            break;
        case 's' :
            cam.lookAt.x-=0.5;
            break;
        case 'd' :
            cam.lookAt.x+=0.5;
            break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int numVert = 0;
    int numNormals= 0;
    int numcoords = 0;
    int numFaces = 0;
    string test;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("spaceship.obj");

    if (!inputFile.good())
        cout << "Problem with Input File";
    else
    {
        while(inputFile >> test) // FIXED
        {
            inputFile >> test; // SHOULD NOT BE HERE

            if (test == "v")
            {
                inputFile >> v[numVert].x;
                inputFile >> v[numVert].y;
                inputFile >> v[numVert].z;
                numVert++;
            }
            else if(test == "vn")
            {
                inputFile >> vn[numNormals].x;
                inputFile >> vn[numNormals].y;
                inputFile >> vn[numNormals].z;
                numNormals++;
            }
            else if(test == "vt")
            {
                inputFile >> vt[numcoords].x;
                inputFile >> vt[numcoords].y;
                inputFile >> vt[numcoords].z;
                numcoords++;
            }
            else if(test == "f")
            {
                string temp;

                for(int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
                {
                    inputFile >> temp;
                    stringstream stream(temp);

                    getline(stream, temp, '/');
                    f[numFaces][count].x = atof(temp.c_str());
                    getline(stream, temp, '/');
                    f[numFaces][count].y = atof(temp.c_str());
                    getline(stream, temp, '/');
                    f[numFaces][count].z = atof(temp.c_str());
                }

                numFaces++;
            }
        }

        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutCreateWindow("rendering a spaceship");
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyboard);
        glutKeyboardFunc(normalKeyboard);

        init();

        glutMainLoop();
    }
}
```

The exact error is as follow "Unhandled exception at 0x779815de in 3dsassignments.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x40000010."

Comment: You should try to narrow down the scope of your question. Where is the exception thrown from?

Comment: You're probably having an 'off-by-one' somewhere in those indices.

Comment: What do you mean where is it thrown? sorry ive never had an error like this before.

Comment: Run this from Visual Studio after ensuring Debug/Exceptions/Win32 has "Access Violations" **checked**. Rest assured you will know right-quick where the violation is. If I had to guess I would surmise your logic for using `while(!inputFile.eof())` for your while-loop control is not terminating when you think it should (and as a side note, it is almost *never* correct to use `.eof()` as a loop control condition). Try `while(inputFile >> test)` and delete the `inputFile >> test;` in the loop body.

Comment: It now compiles and works but my spaceship is not rendered whozCraig that while condition worked thanks now I just need to find out why its not rendering.

Comment: At least you got that going for you =P

Comment: yeh thanks i edited the code to show where the code is at now any ideas to why its not rendering the ship? should i paste the contents of the .obj file?

Comment: also Whozcraig if you post the comment for the exception fix as an answer I will mark the question as answered.

Comment: The "why it isn't rendering" is a different question and should likely be posed as one. For that I would refine the code down to as simple a case as possible. As in clip everything except a single object out and see if that renders. And sure, I can post that as an answer. No worries.

Comment: I did notice in your posted update (which you should always **append**, not change, or people can't see the original question and problem), you're still reading the input line **inside** the while loop. That needs to be removed or you'll be skipping the initial data read done in the `while()` condition block. That was what I meant when I said "delete the `inputFile >> test;` in the loop body."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to catch access violations in Visual Studio is to let their debugger's built-in exception-trap break on violations for you. You can that by Debug/Exceptions/Win32 has "Access Violations" checked, then simply run your program. Note, this will NOT analyze your code. It will catch an exception *if it happens*, not if it *may* happen.

Regarding what is actually *causing* your exception, I would hazard to guess logic for using `!inputFile.eof()` for your while-loop control is not terminating when you think it should (and as a side note, it is almost never correct to use `.eof()` as a loop control condition). Try `while(inputFile >> test)` and delete the inputFile >> test; in the loop body. This will set the fail-bit on the stream when you have reached EOF and attempted to read past it, which it appears is what you are looking for.

**EDIT** After the OP changed the source code, the `inputFile >> test;` is being double-read and consequently skipping the initial value. The second extraction (the one in the loop *body*, not the loop condition expression) needs to be deleted.